# How to sort a python dictionary based on the length of the list of the values

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a contrived example, I have a dictionary that's set up something like this:

```
{
  'a': ['a', 'b'],
  'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}
```

I would like to sort the dictionary by the length of the list (which is the value of each entry) in descending order, so the result should be this:

```
{
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
  'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'a': ['a', 'b']
}
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
sorted_functions = sorted(
  functions.items(),      # Sort the actual items of the dictionary
  key=len(                # Sort on the length of
    operator.itemgetter(  #   the value of the entry, which is
      slice(0, None)      #   a list slice of the whole list
    )
  ),
  reverse=True            # Sort the values in descending order
)
```

However, I get this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'operator.itemgetter' has no len()
```

In the REPL, I tried the following:

```
>>> d = { 'a': ['a'], 'b': ['a', 'b'] }
>>> itemgetter(slice(0, None))(d['a'])
['a']
>>> len(itemgetter(slice(0, None))(d['a']))
1
>>> itemgetter(slice(0, None))(d['b'])
['a', 'b']
>>> len(itemgetter(slice(0, None))(d['b']))
2
```

...so I'm able to get the length of the list, but in the `sorted()` function, it doesn't work.

What do I need to do differently to get the `sorted()` function to sort the way I want it?

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: What type of dictionary do you have, that you're expecting it to retain a sorted order?  A Python `dict` is unsorted by definition.  You can sort the elements with a specified key `len(value)`, but you'll have to put the result in a list, SortedDict, or other structure.

Comment: I understand that dictionaries are unordered, but the goal is to write it to a file in an ordered fashion.

Comment: {k: v for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key= lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True)}

Comment: Note also that in your final line your call len on the whole expression - ie on the *result* of itemgetter - whereas in your original code you call len on itemgetter itself.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Python 3.6+ now supports insertion order for dicts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `sorted` with `key`.

**Ex:**

```
d = {
  'a': ['a', 'b'],
  'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}

print( sorted(d.items(), key= lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True) )
```

**Output:**

```
[('c', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), ('b', ['a', 'b', 'c']), ('a', ['a', 'b'])]
```

*If want to maintain the order.*

```
import collections
d = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key= lambda x: len(x[1]), reverse=True))
print( d )
```

Comment: Ah, I was wondering how to access the entire list but still reference a function instead of a value, and I thought about using lambdas but wasn't sure how to go about it in Python, but this definitely makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: @homersimpson You don’t need to “use lambdas” if that confuses you. A lambda just defines a function, just like a def. Sp if you know what you want your key function to do, you can write `def len_key(item): return len(item[1])`, and then use it like `sorted(d.items(), key=len_key)`.

Comment: Note: `OrderedDict` not necessary with Python 3.6+. The dict in these versions keep insertion order by default.

Comment: @dawg while technically true, the fact that this is implementation-specific means that it shouldn't be relied upon.  Safer to use OrderedDict until 3.7, at which time your comment will become universally accurate.

Answer (score 4):

## Use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

If you want you `dict` to be ordered, you should use an [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). You can sort the items from the first `dict` with a `key`.

### Code

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {
  'a': ['a', 'b'],
  'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}

ordered_d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: -len(i[1])))

print(ordered_d)
```

### Output

```
OrderedDict([('c', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), ('b', ['a', 'b', 'c']), ('a', ['a', 'b'])])
```

## Python 3.6+ `dict` are ordered

Although, if using Python 3.6+, insertion ordered is preserved for `dict`. This is specific to the CPython implementation and will only be an [official language feature starting at version 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html).

### Code

```
d = {
  'a': ['a', 'b'],
  'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}

ordered_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda i: -len(i[1])))

print(ordered_d)
```

### Output

```
{'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'a': ['a', 'b']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lambda`. Like :

```
my_dict = {
  'a': ['a', 'b'],
  'b': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
  'c': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
}
sorted_list = sorted(my_dict.items(), key= lambda value: len(value[1]), reverse=True) #you will get a sorted list,reverse=True will bring longer lists to appear first
print(sorted_list)
sorted_dict = {x[0]:x[1] for x in sorted_list} #convert your sorted list into dictionary
print(sorted_dict)
```

Or you can make it without using dict comprehension as Aran-Fey said:

```
sorted_dict = dict(sorted_list)
```

Comment: You can replace the dict comprehension with `dict(sorted_list)` (or better `OrderedDict(sorted_list)`).

Comment: I have updated my answer. Thanks for your notice.